# 16 vs 32gb ram for photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm about to buy a new laptop because I need photoshop to work faster. I use several hundred layers when I create artwork and my current system is slow and laggy. I am choosing between 16 and 32gb ram. Will this make a significant difference to how photoshop runs, or is 16 gb enough for a good performance?

Comment: Depends how big those layers are 16 Gigabytes is enough for a hundred 2580 x 2580 pixel RGB layers. Offocurse there is then no space for Undo, operating system, other document, browser etc. YMMV Realistically memory is cheap get as much as you can so you dont need to think about this.

Comment: Thank you for that info on number of layers and pixels, that's incredibly helpful.

Comment: Several hundred layers? How about a second, vertical screen for the Layers panel? :))

Comment: This is not a design question.

Comment: @Scott I guess it isn't, but it gets asked often enough on all stacks I thought it worth putting an answer in… just in case it's useful to future searchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is anecdotal rather than 'with citations'…

I have 64GB so my system hangs onto a lot of it even if it's only needed as cache - the more RAM you have the more it will use. Photoshop is currently showing at 10GB, with 46GB total usage. One upside of this is that the scratch disk [& also the system swap file] is almost never used*, so every process stays always in RAM.

[image]

There's no such thing as "too much RAM". If you can afford it, get it. I'd say the same for SSD size. Don't skimp.

*My current swap-file size is 58MB, yes MB, after 8 days uptime.

Running some tests - a 6000x4000 image, layers duplicated 128 times, stays at 10GB RAM until saved [as psB, 10GB file] & then opened afresh. That then pushes my RAM usage to 25GB.
Opening a second copy of the same file pushed RAM usage to 43GB, swap to 8.5GB & as a result the Mac is now busy dumping unused cache & compressing memory in stil-open apps to get memory pressure back into the green.
There's no way I'm going to open a 3rd copy ;)

[image]

After giving it a few minutes to settle…

[image]

BTW, through all this my system stayed fully responsive & I could get on with my other work without even noticing. I can also work on those open images without any noticeable 'lag'. System is doing nicely.

Comment: Yes, ram is only a problem when you run out of it.

Comment: True indeed. No-one ever said "I have too much RAM" in the same way they never said "My computer is too fast" ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, I remember when playing [Xonix](https://www.myabandonware.com/game/xonix-52) on our 286, I had to turn off the turbo button to switch from 16 MHz to 8 MHz or the game would be too fast to play. 

Comment: @Wolff - LOL yup. How times have changed ;)

Comment: Wow thank you for all the helpful responses, this community has helped me so much. @Tetsujin really appreciate that in depth example- the fact your system stayed fully responsive through all of that is everything I need to know!

Comment: Welcome. I'm less certain about how Windows handles memory, but on Mac you're good until that colour coded stripe goes into the red. At that point you can feel things slowing up. Until then it all runs as though nothing else was going on. [This is completely separate to CPU usage, of course, this is purely a RAM/swap file test]